# how to compare two list values using oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle

```
Select main.gr_number from 
(
Select st.GR_NUMBER from student st where upper(st.class_id)=upper('jtm.online137') and st.is_active_flg='Y'
and st.status='STUDYING'
and upper(st.class_days) like  '%'||TO_CHAR(to_date('31-OCT-2019'),'DY')||'%'
) main 
where (Select GR_NUMBER  from student_class_attend where upper(class_id)=upper('jtm.online137')
and attend_date ='31-OCT-2019') not in (main.GR_NUMBER);
```

it is giving me error

> single-row subquery returns more than one row

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like `NOT EXISTS` to me, i.e.

```
SELECT main.gr_number
  FROM (SELECT st.GR_NUMBER
          FROM student st
         WHERE     UPPER (st.class_id) = UPPER ('jtm.online137')
               AND st.is_active_flg = 'Y'
               AND st.status = 'STUDYING'
               AND UPPER (st.class_days) LIKE
                         '%'
                      || TO_CHAR (TO_DATE ('31-OCT-2019', 'dd-mon-yyyy'),
                                  'DY')
                      || '%') main
 WHERE NOT EXISTS
          (SELECT GR_NUMBER
             FROM student_class_attend
            WHERE     UPPER (class_id) = UPPER ('jtm.online137')
                  AND attend_date = TO_DATE ('31-OCT-2019', 'dd-mon-yyyy')
                  AND gr_number = main.GR_NUMBER);
```

Note that I modified your "date" values by applying missing format mask and `TO_DATE` function as you shouldn't compare dates to strings. Even better: use date literal, e.g. date `'2019-10-31'` instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use WHERE with a subquery that returns more than a  row.
Instead of WHERE try using a left join and (for NOT IN) check for null value in left joined key:

```
Select main.gr_number 
from  (
    Select st.GR_NUMBER 
    from student st 
    where upper(st.class_id)=upper('jtm.online137') 
    and st.is_active_flg='Y'
    and st.status='STUDYING'
    and upper(st.class_days) like  '%'||TO_CHAR(to_date('31-OCT-2019'),'DY')||'%'
) main 
LEFT JOIN (
  Select GR_NUMBER  
  from student_class_attend 
  where upper(class_id)=upper('jtm.online137')
    and attend_date ='31-OCT-2019'
)  t ON  t.GR_NUMBER main.GR_NUMBER 
      AND t.GR_NUMBER is null;
```